# correct way to initialize a multidimensional array pointer from a particular address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

I want to create a multidimensional array pointer in C with a particular starting address in memory. I don't fully understand the correct syntax for this. What i want to accomplish to do is something like follows:

```
unsigned char (*vptr)[240][320] =  (unsigned char*)0x40000000;
```

where 
    **vptr[0][0] = 2;** would write 2 to address **0x40000000**;
    **vptr[0][1] = 3;** would write 3 to address **0x40000001**; 
    ...
    **vptr[1][0] = 4;** would write 4 to address **0x40000240**;

So basically that my **vptr** would be functionally equivalent to

```
unsigned char vptr[240][320] = {....};
```

where **&vptr == 0x40000000**.

Could someone please write how this is supposed to be done?
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the address as `(void *)0x40000000` as that can be converted to any object type.  Some compilers might issue a warning unless you cast the address as `(void *)(uintptr_t)0x40000000`.

With `unsigned char (*vptr)[240][320]`, you would need to access the individual `unsigned char` elements using `(*vptr)[i][j]`. Therefore, to make things easier, it would be better to declare `vptr` as `unsigned char (*vptr)[320]` so that `vptr` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `char[320]`.  Then you can access the individual `unsigned char` elements using the more natural syntax `vptr[i][j]`.  For example `vptr[10][20]` would access the `unsigned char` element at address `0x40000000 + (10 * 320) + 20` (`0x40000c94`), or in general, `vptr[i][j]` would access the `unsigned char` element at address `0x40000000 + (i * 320) + j`.

If you don't want to cast the address to `(void *)`, you can cast to the correct pointer type instead.  E.g. `unsigned char (*vptr)[240][320] = (unsigned char (*)[240][320])0x40000000;` or `unsigned char (*vptr)[320] = (unsigned char (*)[320])0x40000000;`. (You might still need the intermediate `(uintptr_t)` cast to avoid a compiler warning.)

You mentioned that `&vptr == 0x40000000` (disregarding casting), but that is not the case.  `vptr` is just a pointer variable at whatever address the compiler and linker decide to place it.  It is the `vptr` variable itself (not its address) that has the value `0x40000000` (disregarding casting).